# C #include pbl.h path

Tags: c, path, c-preprocessor

I'm working on a project on my local machine using C.

I wanted to borrow data structure implementations from PBL
(http://www.mission-base.com/peter/source/)

When I download the zip file from PBL's github repo, there are hundreds of files inside it.

To freely use things from the PBL library, which file should I #include in my project file using    #include "/path/to/pbl.h"?

There are many files in the PBL src folder but I'm suspecting I will have to point to one main header file (enlighten me if I"m wrong)

Second part is where I should place the PBL source files so that

1) since the whole PBL file structure is huge, I don't think I should put it in my project folder... then where should I put it (and call it from)?

2) I also plan to push my project to GitHub, then how can I maintain the file structure dependencies in the remote repo without having to push the whole PBL library up to my repo along with my project files? (correct me if the right thing to do is to push both project files and the PBL library)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

No, you should avoid using anything with an absolute path name such as:

```
#include "/path/to/pbl/pbl.h"
```

You should probably use:

```
#include "pbl.h"
```

and specify a compiler option like:

```
gcc -I/path/to/pbl …
```

to specify where the header is actually found (or headers are found).

You could also look at the documentation for the library.  If it says use a different notation, follow what it says.

Comment: Just in general, for cases like this, should I include the whole PBL src in my project folder or should I keep it somewhere else and advise anyone else trying to execute my program to download it and set up their own path in compiler?

Comment: It's an independent library, albeit one your code is dependent on.  You either need to make it a pre-requisite (and provide information on where to obtain it and, if necessary, how to install it), or make it part of your code — if the licencing on PBL allows you to do so.  You could look into Git sub-modules and related features for ways to include other Git repos as part of your own. But there are issues with 'ease of use' with most of those. On the whole, I'd make it a pre-requisite — but that's mainly because I know that works and I'm sure I don't understand all the ins and outs of t'other.

Comment: yes thank you. I should provide instructions on README or somthing